# Vary the Rendered HTML Tag in a Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am wondering if it is possible to allow a user to decide which html tag will be rendered in a VueJS Component.

For instance, imagine that we have `<my-component>Some Text</my-component>`.

I want to be able to have a property called tag which will determine which html tag is rendered.  So, for example:

```
<my-component tag='a' href="http://some-url.com">Some Text</my-component>
```

Will render to:

```
<a href="http://some-url.com">Some Text</my-component>
```

And:

```
<my-component tag="div">Some Text</my-component>
```

Will render to:

```
<div>Some Text</my-component>
```

And so on for `h1-h6, p, span` and other tags.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do that with [the render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html), using [`createElement`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) and [`$slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Slots). What you described is just writing HTML in a slightly weird way, but here's how you might do it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    myComponent: {
      props: ['tag', 'attributes'],
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement(this.tag || 'div', {attrs: this.attributes || {}}, this.$slots.default);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component tag="h1">A header</my-component>
  <my-component tag="a" :attributes="{href:'http://www.google.com'}">a link to google</my-component>
  <my-component>Default is div</my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.